# How to pass value from textbox to another page without form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok i have this code and i want to send this price from and price to to some other page when user clicks on submit but without refreshing page and without form.On other page i will use this inputs for sql query and display results.

```
Price from:<input type="text" name="from" id="from" width="50px" />
Price to:<input type="text" name="to" id="to" width="50px" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search"/>
```

Comment: Read about ajax in javascript / jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can achieve this using jQuery+Ajax, try this

```
$('#submit').click(function(event) {

        var from = $('#from').val(); 
        var to   = $('#to').val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "page_name.php",
                data:"from="+from+"&to="+to,
                success: function (msg) {

                    //some action
                }
            });

    });
```

and in your php(`page_name.php`) file you can get the posted value and can do the necessary operation

```
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to   = $_POST['to'];
```

Comment: try with new ans. Actually `"` was missing at the end of `"page_name.php`. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

using `jquery`

```
$('#submit').click(){
  event.preventDefault();// prevent form from submitting
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'targetpage.php', //your page here
     data: {price_from:$('#from').val() , price_to: $('#to').val()},
     success: function(response){
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _from = $('#from').val(); 
var _to   = $('#to').val();    
$.post('your_file.php',{from: _form, to: _to},function(data){
    //Do Something with returned data.
},'json');
```

`'json'` at the end could also be `'html'` depending upon what you're returning.